# Django server is hanging in request handler

Tags: python, django

I do a poll once a second, and after some idle time (10min - 1h) the server stops responding. If I press Ctrl-C handler is terminated and the server is back alive. Error after pressing Ctrl-C (while trying to connect with a new client):

```
...same messages repeat...
[22/Sep/2016 21:54:27] "GET /ajax/?id=STATUS_POLL&_=1474566714286 HTTP/1.1" 200 0
[2016-09-22 21:54:28,217: DEBUG/MainProcess] NONE
[22/Sep/2016 21:54:28] "GET /ajax/?id=STATUS_POLL&_=1474566714287 HTTP/1.1" 200 0
[2016-09-23 09:33:14,657: INFO/MainProcess] Starting view
[23/Sep/2016 09:36:34] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 18970
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "c:\python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 128, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "c:\python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 212, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "c:\python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 270, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "c:\python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 194, in send_preamble
    'Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())
  File "c:\python27\lib\socket.py", line 328, in write
    self.flush()
  File "c:\python27\lib\socket.py", line 307, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[23/Sep/2016 09:36:34] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

Request handler:

```
class CTrackerView(TemplateView):

__process = ProcessWrapper()

@staticmethod
def ajax_handler(request):
    if request.GET.get('id', "") == "STATUS_POLL":
        if CTrackerView.__process.is_alive(no_log=False):
           return HttpResponse("UPDATING")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("")
```

process_wrapper.py:

```
class ProcessWrapper:
def is_alive(self, no_log=False):
    if (not hasattr(self, "_process")) or not self._process:
        if not no_log:
            log("NONE", DEBUG)
        return False
```

As you can see from the last code fragment, it just checks the variable is not defined (process is deleted) and return False during all the idle time. (Message "NONE" in log). The problem is difficult to reproduce.

Comment: Its sounds like whatever ProcessWrapper is, it should be done in a celery task

Comment: I've first set up Celery and RabbitMQ but then removed them because its really an overkill and too difficult to manage all these software on customer site just to run a single process. I faced certain problems like tasks do not run but then run on celery restart, but couldn't reproduce it later.

Comment: Sayse, It looks the problem is unrelated with process itself, because it appears when process class is deleted. I thnik it's something related to ajax repeating calls.